# Query listing company name and first order date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, filtering

As the title says, I'm trying to write a query that displays the customerID, company name, and the date of their first order (earliest date listed). I tried Top 1 but that didnt work. Using SQL Server 2012.

```
Select c.CustomerID, CompanyName, top 1 o.OrderDate as 'first order date'
from Customers c join Orders o on
c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
order by c.CustomerID
```

any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select c.CustomerID, CompanyName, MIN(o.OrderDate) as 'first order date'
from
    Customers c
    join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
group by c.CustomerID, CompanyName 
order by c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is more flexible as it allows you to add any columns from the `Customers` table without also having to add them to the `GROUP BY`:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate = MIN(OrderDate)
  FROM dbo.Orders GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, x.OrderDate
  FROM dbo.Customers AS c
  INNER JOIN x ON c.CustomerID = x.CustomerID
  ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```

If you want other columns from the first order, too, such as the order total, you can do this, which you can't add when using `GROUP BY` because the cheapest or most expensive order, for example, will not necessarily correspond with the first order:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, TotalAmount, /* ...other columns... */
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate)
  FROM dbo.Orders GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, x.OrderDate, x.TotalAmount /* ...others... */
  FROM dbo.Customers AS c
  INNER JOIN x ON c.CustomerID = x.CustomerID
  WHERE x.rn = 1
  ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```